# Does having a buddy Pokemon affect spawn rates?

Tags: pokemon-go

I recently set my Pokemon buddy to a Vaporeon. On my latest walk, I ended up encountering four Eevees, which is a significant increase over my zero-Eevees average while walking through the same neighbourhood.

I know that walking x kilometres will give me candy, but this left me wondering if having a Pokemon buddy will also affect the spawn rates *of* that Pokemon nearby. Of course, it could also just be the RNG feeling unusually generous. And, RNGs being what they are, I really have no way to tell the difference without a hell of a lot of extra walking.

Or it could just be global changes of spawn rates for everyone corresponding with the latest patches, and my buddy Pokemon has nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Searching online, the best I could find was [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/525kva/buddy_pokemon_spawns_more_often/) on Silph Road, which is mostly anecdotal reports and speculation without a whole lot of hard data.

So I figured I'd ask here: Does having a buddy Pokemon affect the local spawn rates of that Pokemon? I'm not particularly interested in individual anecdotes so much as statistically significant data, either for or against.

Comment: And I have noticed that spawn patterns have changed with this patch.

Answer (score 12):

No. Spawn rates are not related to individuals. They will occur regardless of level or buddy Pokémon. There is no way to alter this behavior. Spawns will occur independently from your buddy Pokémon.

Comment: Having walked 24km with pikachu as my buddy and having seen zero pikachu spawn during that time, I'm inclined to concur with this answer :)

Comment: One nitpick: there is of course one way to alter the spawn rate behaviour for individuals - by using incense (and walking).

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same experience first with ponyta then tentacool then rydon then tauros. Each time I either only needed one candie to evolve or power up. each time I encountered the same type both using incense and hatching eggs. as soon as I got my first buddy candy I would start catching or hatching that type. Previously I had only hatched these types. I think buddies attract like types for incense and eggs.

Comment: The spawn rates have been definitely changed recently. Do you have any sources for this? I'm inclined to think this is just RNG and a weird coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

My buddy is currently Charizard, I'm on holiday in San Francisco and I cannot got more than a few feet without Charmanders spawning everywhere. Given that none of the local gyms have a Charizard in them I'm really thinking that either there's a Charmander overload or that your buddy does have an effect.

Comment: Between my last three buddies, I did not encounter a single one in the wild - so this does not affect the spawn rate. Based on [Slyph Road](https://thesilphroad.com/atlas#13/37.7637/-122.4584), you just encountered a huge Charmander nest

Comment: On top of what @Wondercricket said, no one puts Charizard in gyms because two of the highest CP Pokémon (Vaporeon and Rhydon) absolutely wipe the floor with Charizard, so it's not a good defender.